# Find a control by String from asp.net Web service

Tags: asp.net, jquery, html, css

Well since it seems relatively difficult to send the object of a WebControl over JSON using jquery.ajax() I've decided to send the name of the control as a string because I know how to do that. Then I promptly realized that, from a web service, I don't actually know how to search for a control by ID name. Since its a service I can't seem to get Control.FindControl() to work so does anyone have ideas or suggestions? All I'm trying to do is call a databind() on my radcombobox.

Thanks in advance!

For any of you that knows anything about asp.net/rad controls - I'm basically updating a database and want the radcombobox to be in sync with that database again after adding something, before I autoselect what was just added. Other than databind do i have to call anything to refresh that list?

Thanks again!

Comment: Can you provide some more details on what you are trying to do?  It sounds like you want to perform data binding via your web service or some other mechanism.  Your web application needs to handle this.  The point of a web service is that it *does not*, *cannot* and *must not* know anything about its callers.  If your ASP.NET application initiates a call to a web service, the *application* - not the web service - needs to manage its own self.

Comment: Okay well really the end result I want is to databind my radcombobox. It was initialized with a databind but there will have been changes to it by the time I want to use it again. I want it to be asynchronous. Am I right in thinking that when re-databind the combobox the list will refresh to the server? Do I also need to refresh its datasource? When inserting I don't actually use asp's datasource insert command - I do it more manually

Comment: When you say the service can't know anything about calling - should there be no actual database handling in there? even if when that actually happens its not a public method?

Comment: The way this is typically done is, you call a service or whatever, and register a callback in your web app that is called when the service call completes.  In that callback, you rebind.

Comment: Could you give a small example - even just a line of code? I'm not sure where the callback goes or anything. I'm rather new to ASP

Comment: I know this is an old question, but what are you binding your radcombobox to? Does it take a Collection, List, or IEnumerable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way i would go in this case is the following:

1. Make some change on the data set
2. Make a call to the web service to update the html page
3. On the service method - i would load the same control and data bind it with the updated data set like this:

```
    // create standard webform
    Page page = new Page();
    HtmlForm form = new HtmlForm();
    page.Controls.Add(form);
    // prepare for rendering
    StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
    StringWriter tw = new StringWriter(html);
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);    

    // load the control to render
    Control control = page.LoadControl("relativeControlPath");
    TypeOfYourControl myControl = (TypeOfYourControl)control;
    myControl.DataSet = GetUpdatedDataSet();
    myControl.DataBind();

    form.Controls.Add(myControl);
    // render
    HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(page, hw, false);

    // pack the output as JSON
    result.Add("html", html.ToString());
    JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string json = ser.Serialize(result);

    return json;
```

`4`. When the ajax call receives a response from the previous step, all i have to do i s to replace the current dom element with the newly rendered one:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    url: "webServiceUrl",
    data: "{'if you need a specific params to identify nature of your control':'" + data + "'}",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result) {
        var output = eval('(' + result.d + ')');
        $("oldNode").remove();
        $("parentNode").append(output.html);
    }
});
```

This approach is generally suitable when you are dealing with composite controls and cannot control or change their behavior.
But for general async update methods i would recommend more lightweight methods like sending serialized data over JSON and using something like jQuery templates on client side for markup generation.